# Problem with tensorflow, TF_SessionRun_wrapper: expected all values in input dict to be ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I try to learn tensorflow, and I wrote my first model. When I try to run this model tensorflow gives

> TypeError: TF_SessionRun_wrapper: expected all values in input dict to be ndarray.

I check type of data in input dict, and they are ndarrays. Probably I wrongly preprocess data, that I feed to model.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

np.random.seed(0)
data, labels = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
num_elements = len(labels)

shuffled_indices = np.arange(len(labels))
np.random.shuffle(shuffled_indices)
shuffled_data = data[shuffled_indices]
shuffled_labels = labels[shuffled_indices]

one_hot_labels = np.zeros([num_elements, 3], dtype=int)
one_hot_labels[np.arange(num_elements), shuffled_labels] = 1

train_data = shuffled_data[0:105]
train_labels = one_hot_labels[0:105]
test_data = shuffled_data[105:]
test_labels = one_hot_labels[105:]


def linear_model(input):
    my_weights = tf.get_variable(name="weights", shape=[4, 3])
    my_bias = tf.get_variable(name="bias", shape=[3])

    linear_layer = tf.matmul(input, my_weights)
    linear_layer_out = tf.nn.bias_add(value=linear_layer, bias=my_bias)
    return linear_layer_out

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 4], name="data_in")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, 3], name="target_labels")

model_out = linear_model(x)

initializer = tf.global_variables_initializer()

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.hinge_loss(logits=model_out, labels=y))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.5).minimize(loss)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(model_out, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(initializer)

    for i in range(1000):
        batch_x, batch_y = train_data[:, :], train_labels[:, :]
        loss_val, _ = sess.run([loss, optimizer], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
```

Comment: I was able to run your code without any problem. What is the version of tensorflow you are using ?

Comment: I use 1.13.1 tensorflow version, and 1.15.4 numpy version.

Comment: It is problem in environment, but I can not say exactly which package. I had this problem using Anaconda with Windows, tried different versions python, tensorflow, numpy, nothing worked out. It helped when I changed today Anaconda to WinPython (WPy-3670), python 3.6.7, tensorflow 1.12.0rc2

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by upgrading

- the `numpy` package to (1.16.2).
- tensorflow to 1.13.1 ,
- Python to 3.6.8 ,
- tensorflow-gpu to 1.13.1

Does not work with version 2.0.A.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two different versions of numpy, it can cause this problem. To solve the problem, you need to delete all numpy libraries after that you can install it again.

2 times run below code ( why two times because most probably you have two different versions.)

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

after that

```
pip install numpy
```

Reference: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25729